# How to combine/bake Displacement and Normal map?

Tags: baking

I've combined a displacement and normal map through a Bump node to add detail to object and I would like to know how I bake it into a single image so it can be used in Unity.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the shader editor create a new image texture node, click on its new button to create  a new texture with the desired resolution, and leave it unconnected and selected.

Switch to cycles, go to bake tab properties panel, select "Normal" and click bake.

After finished baking you can save this new image as Normal map, which will contain bump informations also.

Original (Normal + Voronoi bump):
[image]

Baked Normal only:
[image]

Comment: That's what I do, but it doesn't bake the details from the displacement map connected to the Bump node.

Comment: I noticed that the strenght of your bump map is 0.021, and the normal and displacement  textures are in sRGB color space instead of non-color data. Expecially Normal maps need non-color data space. I think that this little influence gets lost in the color space uncorrect conversion: probably if you use non-color data you'll get all details back.

Comment: I was able to make the metal parts of the object look acceptable, but the leather parts are very faint and low res.